# add multiple pages in C#

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

I'm writing a program in C# which takes information of items from Listview and print it based on the quantity of these items. My problem is that I would like to print a document in multiple pages in c#.

[image: example of my List view]

Here is my code:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            //frame
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 30, 30, 757, 1080);
            //rows
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 30, 184, 787, 184);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 30, 338, 787, 338);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 30, 492, 787, 492);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 30, 646, 787, 646);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 30, 800, 787, 800);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 30, 955, 787, 955);
            //columns
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 282, 30, 282, 1110);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 534, 30, 534, 1110);


            int rows_loc = 35;
            int cols_loc = 70;

            int lable_index = 0;
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {

                for (int quantity = 1; quantity < (Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text) + 1); quantity++)
                {


                    Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16);
                    SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);


                    Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode1 = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
                    Image barcode_image = barcode1.Draw(item.SubItems[2].Text, 20);
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(barcode_image, 40f + cols_loc, 29f + rows_loc);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, font, black, 60f + cols_loc, 0f + rows_loc);

                    lable_index++;
                    row_index = (int)(lable_index / 3);
                    col_index = lable_index % 3;

                    rows_loc = 35 + ((row_index) * 155);
                    cols_loc = 70 + (250 * col_index);

                    if (rows_loc >= e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height)
                    {

                        e.HasMorePages = true;
                        rows_loc = 35;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.HasMorePages = false;

                    }


                }
            }

        }
```

But got the page looks like the figure below with infinite number of pages! I would be very appreciated if someone can help.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The HasMorePages property is an odd kind of rocket science.  The plain bug is that you start iterating the ListView again for each single page.  Always easy to see, every page looks the same.  You need an index variable, set it to 0 in the BeginPrint event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please explain it more